# Имя типа или пространства имен отсутствует в пространстве имен (пропущена ссылка на сборку?)

Tags: c#, office, tfs, ref

Выполняя сборку проекта через Tfs builds, проект выдает ошибку:

> Имя типа или пространства имен "Office" отсутствует в пространстве имен "Microsoft" (пропущена ссылка на сборку?).

При этом ссылка в References проекта указана. В коде тоже указано:

> using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

Также в процессе сборки проекта на сервере возникает Warning:

> Не удалось разрешить данную ссылку. Не удалось обнаружить сборку "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=15.0.0.0,...". Убедитесь, что данная сборка существует на диске. Если данная ссылка требуется в коде, это может вызвать ошибки компиляции.

При этом, локально, проект успешно собирается.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Для этого необходимо выбрать соответствующий Build controller в настройках сборки во вкладке Build Defaults.